# Listen for layout changes in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, android-layout

How can I get notified when a layout pass has finished? Is there something like `onLayoutFinished()` that I can implement or override somewhere?

From the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) javadoc:

> Layout is a two pass process: a
>   measure pass and a layout pass. The
>   measuring pass is implemented in
>   measure(int, int) and is a top-down
>   traversal of the view tree. Each view
>   pushes dimension specifications down
>   the tree during the recursion. At the
>   end of the measure pass, every view
>   has stored its measurements. The
>   second pass happens in layout(int,
>   int, int, int) and is also top-down.
>   During this pass each parent is
>   responsible for positioning all of its
>   children using the sizes computed in
>   the measure pass.

What I'd like is to execute some logic after the "second pass" has finished. In particular, I want to make some changes to a view, and then make changes to another view that depend of the frame (position and size) of the first view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply override onLayout() and do whatever you need to do after calling super.onLayout(). You can also override onSizeChanged(), which will be invoked only when a layout pass changes the coordinates/size of a View.

Comment: I tried overriding onLayout() but things didn't behave like I expected. Since it felt like I was fighting against the way the platform does things, I finally decided to calculate the results of the layout pass on the first view, and request changes to the layout of the second view based on that. The views are then changed together during the same layout pass.